# How to toggle Notification.permission in electron application?

Tags: javascript, notifications, electron

I have developed a desktop application based on electron framework. I have loaded my website inside the browser window. The website will display notifications to the user.
In chrome I have an option to **request permission** from the user to display notification or not. By using **Notification.requestPermission()** I can display a popup to request permission from the user for notification to display or not.

The same way I need to display the same popup to toggle notification permission from **"granted"** to **"denied"**.

Suggest me how to enable this feature in electron application.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Electron default browser notifications don't work very well (On some platforms they didn't even send).

Instead I recommend you use a node-js notification package called [`node-notifier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier).

I've been using it for about a year now in my Electron app and I would recommend it to all users of Electron.

Node notifier works on every platform and you don't need to ask for permission to send notifications.

[Node notifier NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier)

Comment: By using the  [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier) I can create my own notifications. But in my case my website is already giving out notifications. I need to get Permission from user whether to display it or not, like the one done in browsers like chrome. Modifying my website's code will be tedious process, so a popup that could ask permission from the user whether to allow or block, so that it will change my app's notification permission **(Notification.permission)** to **"blocked" or "granted"**. Please suggest me a way to enable the popup.

Comment: I understand what you mean since my app has both browser and desktop notifications. Unfortunately this was the only way I could get it working. I can't suggest anything else.

Comment: Thanks for valuable time. If you find the answer sometimes please notify me.

Comment: @GrantWard did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try and create an empty notification without showing it. This will trigger the permission ask:

```
//Modules
const { Notification } = require('electron');

//On ready
app.on('ready', () => {
    new Notification();
});
```